# How can I view MUI library of components and API's offline?

Tags: terminal, material-ui, material-components, material-components-ios

**I want to be able to view MUI's components library and api docs on my mac while I'm offline. I was given the below instructions by MUI support**

This is what I put into my terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui.git
cd material-ui
yarn
yarn docs:build
yarn docs:start
```

this is what I get out of  [my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AlTJ.png)

```
apple2@apple2s-iMac material-ui % yarn docs:start
yarn run v1.22.10
$ yarn workspace docs start
$ next start
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
    at doListen (node:net:1516:7)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 3000
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: /usr/local/Cellar/node/17.3.0/bin/node
Arguments: /Users/apple2/Desktop/Code/material-ui/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.10.js start
Directory: /Users/apple2/Desktop/Code/material-ui/docs
Output:

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/workspace for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
apple2@apple2s-iMac material-ui %
```

should I add the terminal outputs for each command input? (yarn docs:build is a large number of lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message `EADDRINUSE` is telling you that you already have something listening on port 3000.  You need to stop the process/application currently using port 3000 so you can run MUI docs  *or* tell MUI docs to use another port.

You can do one of the following:

- Tell MUI docs to run on a different port: `yarn docs:start --port=3001` (This is probably your best option.)
- Look for the application (probably another terminal window -- your other React app?) and stop it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
- Reboot your machine and make sure that nothing starts up listening on port 3000.
- Find the process id in terminal and kill it manually.

**To find the process id in terminal and kill it manually, open up terminal on your Mac and type the following commands:**

*Get a list of any processes listening on port 3000 (`sudo` will require you to enter your password)*

```
sudo lsof -i :3000
```

*A list of processes currently listening on port 3000 will be displayed. For example:*

```
COMMAND   PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    53763 [your username]   28u  IPv4 0x6c9dbf461b729ff1      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

*Find the process id (PID) in the list for the process you want to kill -- in the example above, the process id is "53763".*

*Kill the process:*

```
kill -9 53763
```

*Now try to re-run MUI docs:*

```
yarn docs:start
```